# Transpose with PROC SQL

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

A minimal example:

```
DATA my_data;
INPUT id name $;
DATALINES;
10 Adam
20 Bob
;


DATA my_data2;
INPUT id name $ value year;
DATALINES;
10 Adam 100 2010
10 Adam 200 2017
20 Bob  300 2010
20 Bob  400 2017
;


PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE TEST AS 
SELECT A.ID, A.NAME,
CASE WHEN B.YEAR = 2010 THEN B.VALUE ELSE . END,
CASE WHEN B.YEAR = 2017 THEN B.VALUE ELSE . END
FROM MY_DATA A 
LEFT JOIN MY_DATA2 B ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.NAME = B.NAME
;
QUIT;
```

The output I get is:

```
10  Adam  100  .
10  Adam  .    200
20  Bob   300  .
20  Bob   .    400
```

But the output I want is:

```
10  Adam 100 200
20  Bob  300 400
```

I get that the join is the issue but I'm not 100% what my approach should be.

Comment: Try with conditional aggregation, grouping by `id` and `name` and using the `CASE` inside a `MAX`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GROUPING with respect to  ID and NAME columns, and famous aggregate functions
 ( *MIN* or *MAX* ) :

```
SELECT A.ID, A.NAME,
MIN(CASE WHEN B.YEAR = 2010 THEN B.VALUE ELSE NULL END) VALUE1,
MIN(CASE WHEN B.YEAR = 2017 THEN B.VALUE ELSE NULL END) VALUE2
FROM MY_DATA A 
LEFT JOIN MY_DATA2 B ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.NAME = B.NAME
GROUP BY A.ID, A.NAME
ORDER BY A.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to @EzLo.

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE TEST AS 
        SELECT A.ID, A.NAME,
            MAX(CASE WHEN B.YEAR = 2010 THEN B.VALUE ELSE . END),
            MAX(CASE WHEN B.YEAR = 2017 THEN B.VALUE ELSE . END)
        FROM MY_DATA A 
            LEFT JOIN MY_DATA2 B ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.NAME = B.NAME
        GROUP BY A.ID, A.NAME
;
QUIT;
```